# How to block ordering feature from backend when company/customer is set inactive in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

How to block ordering from admin panel, when a company/customer status is blocked or inactive state. I am using B2B feature which has company module and version is magento 2.2.2 i am able to block orders from front-end when they are not active but how to achieve from back-end..?